# docker-compose same config for dev and production but enable code sharing between host and container only in development

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

As the most important benefit of using docker is to keep dev and prod env to be the same so let's rule out the option of using two different `docker-compose.yml`

Let's say we have a Django application, and we use `gunicorn` to serve for production and we have a dedicated apache2 as a reverse proxy(this apache2 is out of docker by design). So this application(docker-compose) has only two parts, `web`(Django) and `db`(mysql). There's nothing wrong with the db part.

For the Django part, the dev routine without docker would be using venv and `python3 manage.py runserver` or whatever shortcut that an IDE provides. We can happily change our code, the dev server is smart to pick up and change and reflect in no time.

Things get tricky when docker comes in since all source code should be packed into the image, this gives our dev a big overhead of recreating the image&container again and again. One might have the following solutions(which I found not elegant):

- In `docker-compose.yml` use volume to mount source code folder into the container, so that all changes in the host source code folder will automatically reflect in the container, then `gunicorn` will pick up the change and reflect. --- This does remove most of the recreating container overhead, but we can't use the same `docker-compose.yml` in production as this introduces a dependency to the source code on the host server.
- I know there is a command line option to mount a host folder to the container, but to my knowledge, this option only exists in `docker run` not `docker-compose`. So using a different command to bring the service up in different env is another dead end. ( *I am not 100% sure about this as I'm still quite new to docker, please correct me if I'm wrong*)

TLDR;
How can I set up my env so that

- I use only one single `docker-compose.yml` for both dev and prod
- I'm able to dev with live changes easily without recreating docker container

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `big overhead of recreating the image&container again and again` - `COPY src` should take <1s or thomething about that. Only reinstalling requirements/prerequisites takes time. Share your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin on a lot of non-linux docker dev setups copy the files over involves copy every file in the build context into the vm. re-building with just COPY can end up taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your django service in `docker-compose.yml` as

```
services:
  backend:
    image: backend
```

Then add a file for dev: `docker-compose.dev.yml`

```
services:
  backend:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.yml
      service: backend
    volume: local_path:path
```

To launch for prod, just `docker-compose up`

To launch for dev
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up`

To hot reload dev django app, just reload gunicorn `ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep greencar_proj | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -HUP`

Comment: I guess this is the best solution I ever heard of, thanks!

Comment: Wait, `extends` is not supported in version 3?

Comment: unfortunately no. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101. for now you would have repeat youself for backend definition...

Answer (score 2):

I have also liked to jam as much functionality into a single docker-compose.yml file. A few strategies I would consider:

1. define different services for prod and dev. So you'll run `docker-compose up dev` or `docker-compose up prod` or `docker-compose run dev`. There is some copying here but usually not a lot.
2. Use multiple docker-compose.yml files and merge them. eg: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`. More details here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

I usually just comment out my volumes section, but that's probably not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out!